# php cake Auth inside class

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to check if a user is existing in the mgrUser table. now the propblem is the controller is in the adminController while the model is in the mgrUserModel. how do i use Auth for this? Thats the reason why I made a generic login code.

```
public function login() {
         // if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        //     return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        // }
        // $this->Flash->error(
        //     __('Username ou password incorrect')
        // );


        //since the model is in a different view, I needed to includ the mgrModel and create a generic login
        //will revamp the code to fit the built in Aut code for php cake
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $User_ID = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_id']);
            $Pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']); 

            try {
                    $mgrUserModel = new MgrUser();
                    $isValid = $mgrUserModel->find('first', array(
                        'conditions' => array("user_id" => $User_ID)
                    ));
                    if($isValid != null){
                        if (($isValid['MgrUser']['pass']) == $Pass) {
//this doesnot work
$this->Auth->allow();
                            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    //echo "not logged in";
                } 
            // this echo will show the id and pass that was taken based on the user_id and pass that the user will input
            //for testing only
            // echo $isValid2['MgrUser']['id'];
            // echo $isValid2['MgrUser']['pass'];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need double `==` to compare things,

```
function checkMe()
{
    if($user == 'me'){
        $this->Auth->allow('detail');
    }
}
```

what you did was assign `"me"` string to variable `$user` which always returns `true` because assignment was possible
Anyway you should use it in `beforeFilter` which is running before every action from this controller, which makes much more sense

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    if($user == 'me'){
        $this->Auth->allow('detail');
    }
}
```

Comment: actually that one was just a sample, the real problem is the  $this->Auth->allow('detail'); is not working even if the condition is satisfied (its in a different code)

Comment: already tried that to. but the command will only be executed when a button is clicked. so it is in a function verify(){//}

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte so provide complete example of your issue and all relative code snippets, so someone can any chance to help solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

the `Auth` component could be configured to read the user information via another `userModel` (The model name of the users table). It defaults to `Users`.

please consult the book for appropriate cakephp version: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers